# filter operator in fromEvent function does not work in RxJS6

Tags: rxjs

I'm new to RxJ. 
The version of RxJS 6.2.

I'm trying fromEvent method and filtering out mouse event info but it shows mouse position data even when clientX is bigger than 500 and seems filter method is not working.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

## JavaScript

```
import { Observable, fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

let numbers = [1, 5, 10];

const source = fromEvent(document, "mousemove");
source.pipe(
  map((e: MouseEvent) => {
    return {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY
    }
  }),
  filter(value => value.x < 500)
)

source.subscribe(
    value => console.log(value),
    e => console.log(`error: ${e}`),
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `pipe` returns a new observable - which you are ignoring. It does not modify the `source` observable.

You should subscribe to the observable returned by `pipe` instead of the `source` observable:

```js
const source = fromEvent(document, "mousemove");

const mappedAndFiltered = source.pipe(
  map((e: MouseEvent) => {
    return {
      x: e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY
    };
  }),
  filter(value => value.x < 500)
);

mappedAndFiltered.subscribe(
  value => console.log(value),
  e => console.log(`error: ${e}`),
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm new to RxJS and having a hard time to learn RxJS. It seems there were many changes from v5 to v6.

Comment: No worries. The learning curve is a little steep, but if you stick with it, it should be worth it.